# how to get/set component size dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a DIV container that has a paragraph and another inner DIV displayed in line.
Inner DIV is unknown but it's always the same and not gonna change. I can sent min-width if needed. Now based on outer DIV size I need to either cut (with three dots) or show full paragraph string. But I have to set paragraph width in css to show that three dots when outer div size is too small.

```
<div className="divOuter">
  <p>very long string</p>
  <div className="divInner">some div stuff</div>
</div>

.p {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: ?????;               // what do I set here?????
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.divInner {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  align-items: center;
}


|--------------------------------------|
|very long string        some div stuff|
|--------------------------------------|

need to get this when outer DIV resized:
|------------------------------|
|very long st... some div stuff|
|------------------------------|

|--------------------|
|ve... some div stuff|
|--------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

You don't need to give any width to the long string `p` element.

There is a property of `flexbox` called `flex`. When you set this to `1`, it will elongate that element to take up the remaining horizontal space in the parent.

After that, you just have to give `text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;` to make the `...` appear.

Run the below snippet to see it working.

```css
.divOuter {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.longString {
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.divInner {}
```

```html
<div class="divOuter">
  <p class="longString">very long string very long string very long string very long string very long string</p>
  <p class="divInner">some div stuff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: divOuter should be not fixed size. It should be e.g. 100% page width. And when I make page size too small then it should show ... three dots for paragraph and no divInner change.. See example in my question

Comment: Hi @JohnGlabb. Have updated my answer. Basically it doesn't matter what width you give to `divOuter`. You don't need to give it a width at all. It will automatically show you `...` when the page size is too small. Check it out by running the snippet again.

Comment: than works perfect.. Thank you Mr. Nisanth

Comment: @JohnGlabb. Glad to have helped :).